# Photo organizer for network and multiple users

Tags: windows, photography

In the past we have used Picasa, which was great, but a lot of the information was sitting in the specific Windows user account being used, and also information was tied to specific (directory) paths.

Now I am looking for something where:

1. Important information is stored independently from the machine I am working from.
2. We can work from different devices (primarily Windows, but preferably Android as well).
3. Paths (for directories) can change.

Comment: Which photo organizing features do you need? (Please add them to your question)

Comment: (Something lie Picasa :-)  I think I would like to know about software satisfying these criteria, and then look at other features

Comment: With the newest version of Picasa you can change the database location the setting is under **Experimental Features**.

Comment: I have been looking at picasastarter : https://sites.google.com/site/picasastartersite/home - ROughly the same (?) except with picasastarter you can have multiple DBs. (I assume then all thumbnails would be remote.  IS that not a disadvantage)?